# Laravel: How to Compare 2 Collection Attributes

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am sending data to my view as below;

I am displaying all contacts in a multi select form and trying to get "**selected**" printed in options listings. (Then I will use jquery to populate the select field with chosen plugin) In my other pages, nested foreach loop works(something like below), it works `@if` check is checking against a single value. But now, I have multiple values to check. Nested foreach loop fails (see below)

```
$contacts = ContactDirectory::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customer_id)->get(); //Say 50 contacts
$rfito = rfito::where('rfi_id',$rfiid)->get(); // say 5 contacts
```

then

```
@foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    @foreach ($rfito as $rfito) 
        <option value="{{$contact->id}}" @if($contact->id == $rfito->contact_id) selected @endif > 
            {{$contact->firstname}}  
        </option>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I thin you have a mistake `@foreach ($rfitos as $rfito)` is what you need

Comment: Wow! yup that did it. Thanks  @OlegNurutdinov

Comment: You're welcome :)